# Use both buttons and dropdowns in discord py v2

Tags: python, discord.py, dropdown, discord-buttons

I'm trying to create a command in my Discord bot using discord.py where I want to use both buttons and dropdowns (select menus) together, similar to the help command in Dank Memer bot. I have created separate classes for buttons (Buttons) and select menus (categorySelect), and they work fine individually. However, when I try to use both of them together in a single command, I'm facing an issue.

I have tried putting both the Buttons and categorySelect instances into a list and passing it to the View class, but it didn't work as expected

````
class Buttons(discord.ui.View):

    def __init__(self, *, timeout=15):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.click = False

    @discord.ui.button(label="Rock",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="easy") # or .primary
    async def rock_button(self,interaction:discord.Interaction,child:discord.ui.Button):
        for child in self.children:
            child.disabled=True

        win_embed = discord.Embed(title="You win !",description="**Your Choice:** Rock\n**Xynox Choice:** Scissors✂️",color=discord.Color.green())
        loss_embed = discord.Embed(title="You lose !",description="**Your Choice:** Rock\n**Xynox Choice:** Paper",color=discord.Color.red())
        tie_embed = discord.Embed(title="It's a tie !",description="**Your Choice:** Rock\n**Xynox Choice:** Rock",color=discord.Color.blurple())
        embed = random.choice([win_embed, loss_embed, tie_embed])
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=embed, view=self)



class categorySelect(View):

    @discord.ui.select(
                        placeholder='Select a category',
                        options=[
                            discord.SelectOption(label='Guns', value = "1", description='Dangerous Guns stolen from the government', emoji='<:golden_sniper:1123954953640218724>'),
                            discord.SelectOption(label='Drugs', value = "2", description='Drugs that can be used to get high', emoji='<:weed:1124062866505486356>'),
                            discord.SelectOption(label='Swords', value = "3", description='The Ancient Blades of Death', emoji='⚔️'),
                            # discord.SelectOption(label='Go Back', value = "3", description='Go Back!!!', emoji='↩️'),
                        ]
                    )
    
    async def select_option_callback(self, interaction, select):
        
        if select.values[0] == "1":

            snack_embed = discord.Embed(title='Guns', description='Reload em', color=discord.Color.random())
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=snack_embed, view=categorySelect())

        
        elif select.values[0] == "2":
        
            snack_embed = discord.Embed(title='Drugs', description='Get High', color=discord.Color.random())
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=snack_embed, view=categorySelect())
        


class help(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @app_commands.command(name='help', description='Gives info about all the commands')
    async def help(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help", description="Use the dropdown to select a category", color=discord.Color.random())
        category = categorySelect()
        button = Buttons()
        cl = [category, button]
        #use both of these together
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, view=cl)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse views with components. A `View` is a type of object that will store all its components. You can, without any problem, create a `view` and add buttons and selects to it (the components) using the `@discord.ui.button()` and `@discord.ui.select()` decorators, respectively.
So, your code should look like this:

```py
import discord


# make your code more readable
SELECT_OPTIONS = [
    discord.SelectOption(label='Guns', value = "1", description='Dangerous Guns stolen from the government', emoji='<:golden_sniper:1123954953640218724>'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Drugs', value = "2", description='Drugs that can be used to get high', emoji='<:weed:1124062866505486356>'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Swords', value = "3", description='The Ancient Blades of Death', emoji='⚔️'),
    discord.SelectOption(label='Go Back', value = "4", description='Go Back!!!', emoji='↩️')
]


class HelpView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, timeout=15):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Rock", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def rock_button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button:discord.ui.Button):
        # do something
        pass

    @discord.ui.select(placeholder='Select a category', options=SELECT_OPTIONS, max_values=1)
    async def select_option_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        # do something
        pass
```